# Brown rice syrup availability in India

Tags: baking

I want to buy Lundberg Brown Rice Syrup for my baking needs. Is it available in India or, if not, from an online vendor without exorbitant delivery charges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can buy the same online from [eBay](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Lundberg-Sweet-Dreams-Brown-Rice-Syrup-1-lb-5-oz-/282176852354), Free Shipping!

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. i appreciate it but as i mentioned in my question, there is always a very high charge on these products even for one unit. i was looking for a place where they do not charge the whole cost on one delivery. actual cost is 450rs or less and its more than 6000 bucks...